# Alternative for JSON_ENCODE to be called in d3js graph

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I need to plot d3.js histogram and i have troube in plotting the data from database.
php code is as follows.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","a");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  `b` FROM  `h` LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $s1[] = $row['b'];  
$length=count($s1);
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) 
{ 
$a = array(preg_replace("([c]+)", "",$s1[$i] ));
$b=(str_replace(array( '(', ')') , '', $a));
print_r($b);
$p=implode(" ",$b);
print_r($p);
$co=array_map('strval', explode(',', $p));
echo '</br>'."my array";
print_r($co);
}
}
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  `a` FROM  `h` LIMIT 1");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{

$s2[] = $row1['a'];  
$length1=count($s2);
for($j=0;$j<$length1;$j++) 
{ 
$a1 = array(preg_replace("([c]+)", "",$s2[$j] ));
$b1=(str_replace(array( '(', ')') , '', $a1));
print_r($b1);
$p1=implode(" ",$b1);
print_r($p1);

$co1=array_map('strval', explode(',', $p1));

echo '</br>'."my array2..........";
print_r($co1);
} 
}

$map=array_map(null,$co1,$co);
echo "<br>";
echo JSON_ENCODE($map);
echo "<br>";

$object = new stdClass();

$length5=count($s2);
// echo "lennnnnnnnn".$length5;
for($l=0;$l<7;$l++) { 

foreach ($map[$l] as $key => $value)
{
if($key == 0)
$object -> a = $value;
else if($key == 1)
$object -> b = $value;


}
$newArr[$l] = JSON_ENCODE($object);

}
print_r($newArr);


mysqli_close($con); 

?>
```

printing array using, 
    print_r($newArr); 
displays the following,

```
Array ( [0] => {"a":"26.5","b":"80"} [1] => {"a":" 27","b":" 222"} [2] =>  {"a":"           27.5","b":" 303"} [3] => {"a":" 28","b":" 408"} [4] => {"a":" 28.5","b":" 276"} [5] => {"a":" 29","b":" 151"} [6] => {"a":" 29.5","b":null} )
```

in d3js code,

```
var bins = <?php echo JSON_ENCODE($newArr) ; ?>;
bins.forEach(function(bin) {
bin.a = +bin.a;
bin.b = +bin.b;
});
```

displays the following,

```
["{\"a\":80,\"b\":26.5}","{\"a\":222,\"b\":27}","    {\"a\":303,\"b\":27.5}","{\"a\":408,\"b\":28}","{\"a\":276,\"b\":28.5}","{\"a\":151,\"b\":29}","  {\"a\":null,\"b\":29.5}"]
```

I need to call this output in my d3.js code using echo json_encode. When using this,    the data creates forward slashes "\" with the numbers and so the numbers are not read as input for the graph. Is there any way to remove the slashes or to take the data with any other alternate code or function?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a complete example, but it looks like you're double `json_encode`ing. You `json_encode` array of already `json_encode`d values.

Comment: How to remove what? json_encoding? It's in your code, I can't tell you.

Comment: Replace `$newArr[$l] = JSON_ENCODE($object);' with `$newArr[$l]=$object` ?

Comment: output is like this,

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [a] => 29.5 [b] => ) )

Comment: s.. this is the output

Comment: can u help me solving this?

Comment: What does "s.. this is the output" mean? I'm still to find out what is it you're feeding to json_encode and what's the output. So far you've provided a lot of contradictory data.